# Same response with different headers from api

Tags: python, python-requests, aiohttp

I am working on some exchange platform called Backpack. I stuck on some mystery problem with same response, when the headers are completely different.

I have come to the conclusion that server just caches request and returns it with same data.

Things I've tried: different proxies for requests, headers are different as much as it possible, waiting after first request 10 seconds, aiohttp, requests, connection with Session and cleaning cache after first response and without session.

Headers I've tried:

```
'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
'Pragma': 'no-cache',
'Expires': '0',
'User-Agent': (random useragent for both requests),
"Connection": "close",
```

The only thing that make API return not same response is changing body params, but for me it's not an option.

How can I avoid caching?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved by using proxies on another domain.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).